# Django saving data in model through model form and foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a model named **Doctor** and a model named **Appoint** which have *doctor as a foreign key*. and I have a model form to take input for the Appoint model but not for the foreign key in it. I am able to link the Doctor model through url but I am not able to save doctor(foreign key) in Appoint model.

here are the 2 models:-

````
``` class Doctor(models.Model):
    docid = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=1001)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    add = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=doc_cat,max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Appoint(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    phone1 = models.IntegerField()
    phone2 = models.IntegerField()
    add = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    timeslot = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    symptom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.f_name + self.l_name```
````

here is the view method:-

````
``` def takeappointment(request, docid):
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(docid = docid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Appointform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            f_name = request.POST['f_name']
            l_name = request.POST['l_name']
            day = request.POST['day']
            timeslot = request.POST['timeslot']
            email = request.POST['email']
            return render(request, 'submit.html', {
                'f_name' : f_name,
                'l_name' : l_name,
                'day' : day,
                'timeslot' : timeslot,
                'email' : email,
                })   
    form = Appointform()
    return render(request, 'takeappointment.html', {'form': form, 'doctor': doctor})
 ```
````

how can save the foreign key from Doctor model along with form data in Appoint model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:
add doctor parameter to your `Appointform`

```
class Appointform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appoint

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.from_doctor = kwargs.pop("from_doctor", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        cleaned_data["doctor"] = self.from_doctor
        return cleaned_data
```

and in your `takeappointment` view add this parameter when create form

```
def takeappointment(request, docid):
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(docid = docid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Appointform(request.POST, from_doctor=doctor)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            f_name = request.POST['f_name']
            l_name = request.POST['l_name']
            day = request.POST['day']
            timeslot = request.POST['timeslot']
            email = request.POST['email']
            return render(request, 'submit.html', {
                'f_name' : f_name,
                'l_name' : l_name,
                'day' : day,
                'timeslot' : timeslot,
                'email' : email,
                })   
    form = Appointform(from_doctor=doctor)
    return render(request, 'takeappointment.html', {'form': form, 'doctor': doctor})
```

you also need to change definition of Appoint model, add `blank=True` to your `doctor`  field

```
doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

you can do it other way.

```
class Appointform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appoint
        exclude = ("doctor", )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.from_doctor = kwargs.pop("from_doctor", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.doctor = self.from_doctor
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This error is coming:                             TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'from_doctor'

Comment: did you change __init__ of your `appointform`? need to add 
        `self.from_doctor = kwargs.pop("from_doctor", None)`

Comment: Yes it works but the problem yet to be solved. i am still seeing the dropdown inside my database. i want that the doctor feild in my Appoint model should have the name of the doctor whose id is passed in url.

Comment: don't show `doctor` field of your form in template, it will be filled by value you provide in `from_doctor` parameter.

Comment: added another variant, how can you change `appointform`

Comment: Man !!! you have been a great help. thanyou so muchhh